# How to get X hours after specific hour in mysql?

Tags: mysql, loops

For example, given 1339372800, which is Mon, 11 Jun 2012 00:00:00 GMT, I would like to get the next X hours including 1339372800. So for the next 3 hours, the result would be

```
+------------+
| hours      |
+------------+
| 1339372800 |
| 1339376400 |
| 1339380000 |
+------------+
```

I think I need to create a loop but I don't know how to proceed from that. Thanks.

Comment: Why do this in MySQL?  It's often much easier in one's application code...

Comment: Because I need to left join it with a view that gets the count of rows per hour. If there are no entries for that particular hour I would like the entry to be 0.

Comment: But why not just draw that inference within your application when an hour is not present in the resultset?

Comment: I guess that's possible, but I'd like to know a MySQL solution as well.

Comment: Well, as I said, it's often much easier in one's application code... the MySQL solution is essentially that which @hangy proposed in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10977935/623041).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a numbers table as [Creating a "Numbers Table" in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9751318/11963) that contains all hours for a considerate amount of time, and query that:

```
SELECT hour
FROM hours
WHERE hour >= 1339372800
ORDER BY hour ASC
LIMIT 3
```

That makes the query really easy, and the table should not be too big, either. (Less than 90k rows for 10 years.)

Comment: Hmm, that could work. But I guess I'm looking for a more elegant solution (no offense). If I can't find any other that works I'll go with yours.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE 
hours between 1339372800 and DATE_SUB(1339372800, INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
```