# Inserting values in one field from numerous fields in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have large table, with around 200 fields. Around a 100 of those fields are to be mapped to one field when creating a dimension table from it. The problem is I have to add the values of those 100 fields one-by-one through like a 100 insert statements. Is there like a loop or something with which i can achieve this more efficiently?

Here's an example of the code:

```
    insert into DimTableA(visit_no, patient, facility, icd9, icd9_flag, ip_op)
    select D.registration, D3.med_number, D3.Hosp_Id, D.final_diagnosis_18,'d',IF(D3.Admit_Type in(1,2,3),'Inpatient','Outpatient'),
    from svch_dischs3_s D3, svch_diags_s D

    insert into DimTableA(visit_no, patient, facility, icd9, icd9_flag, ip_op)
    select D.registration, D3.med_number, D3.Hosp_Id, D.final_diagnosis_19,'d',IF(D3.Admit_Type in(1,2,3),'Inpatient','Outpatient'),
    from svch_dischs3_s D3, svch_diags_s D

    insert into DimTableA(visit_no, patient, facility, icd9, icd9_flag, ip_op)
    select D.registration, D3.med_number, D3.Hosp_Id, D.final_diagnosis_20,'d',IF(D3.Admit_Type in(1,2,3),'Inpatient','Outpatient'),
    from svch_dischs3_s D3, svch_diags_s D;
```

......... and so on

The only field name that changes is the 'icd9' input( i.e D.final_diagnosis_18, final_diagnosis_19, final_diagnosis_20 ....)

Any help would be really appreciated, lads. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could unpivot those columns using a cross join to a fixed set of numbers like this:

```
insert into DimTableA (
  visit_no,
  patient,
  facility,
  icd9,
  icd9_flag,
  ip_op
)
select
  D.registration,
  D3.med_number,
  D3.Hosp_Id,
  case N.number
    when 1 then D.final_diagnosis_18
    when 2 then D.final_diagnosis_19
    when 3 then D.final_diagnosis_20
    ...
  end,
  'd',
  IF(D3.Admit_Type in(1,2,3),'Inpatient','Outpatient')
from
  svch_dischs3_s D3,
  svch_diags_s D,
  (
    select 1 as number union all
    select 2           union all
    select 3           union all
    ...  /* up to the number of columns to unpivot */
  ) N
```

You could [create and populate a persistent numbers table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751318/creating-a-numbers-table-in-mysql) instead of the inline view and use the necessary subset of that table in your query. In that case the query would change like this

```
...
from
  svch_dischs3_s D3,
  svch_diags_s D,
  numbers N
where N.number between 1 and … /* the number of columns to unpivot */
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try running a single `INSERT` with a [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html) in the sub select.

Your current SQL has a [Cartesian join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) in it so I am going to take a guess that you are missing a join somewhere. Anyway, this should give you an idea of what I am driving at:

```
insert into DimTableA(visit_no, patient, facility, icd9, icd9_flag, ip_op)
select D.registration, D3.med_number, D3.Hosp_Id, D.final_diagnosis_18,'d',IF(D3.Admit_Type in(1,2,3),'Inpatient','Outpatient')
from svch_dischs3_s D3, svch_diags_s D
-- where D3.???? = D.????
union
select D.registration, D3.med_number, D3.Hosp_Id, D.final_diagnosis_19,'d',IF(D3.Admit_Type in(1,2,3),'Inpatient','Outpatient')
from svch_dischs3_s D3, svch_diags_s D
-- where D3.???? = D.????
union
select D.registration, D3.med_number, D3.Hosp_Id, D.final_diagnosis_20,'d',IF(D3.Admit_Type in(1,2,3),'Inpatient','Outpatient')
from svch_dischs3_s D3, svch_diags_s D
-- where D3.???? = D.????;
```

Here is a more theoretical example:

```
create table dimTable
(id int unsigned not null default 0,
field varchar(50)
);

create table sourceTable
(id int unsigned not null default 0,
field1 varchar(50),
field2 varchar(50),
field3 varchar(50),
field4 varchar(50),
field5 varchar(50)
);

insert into sourceTable (id,field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) values (1,"hello","these","are","some","values");
insert into sourceTable (id,field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) values (2,"hello2","these2","are2","some2","values2");
insert into sourceTable (id,field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) values (3,"hello3","these3","are3","some3","values3");
insert into sourceTable (id,field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) values (4,"hello4","these4","are4","some4","values4");
insert into sourceTable (id,field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) values (5,"hello5","these5","are5","some5","values5");

insert into dimTable (id, field)
select id,field1 from sourceTable
union
select id,field2 from sourceTable
union
select id,field3 from sourceTable
union
select id,field4 from sourceTable
union
select id,field5 from sourceTable;

select *
from dimTable;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, Tom. Yeah, i missed the where clause..it's there in my actual code though..your example helps alot, but i was looking for something more space-efficient..like a cursor or something, you know what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure would solve your problem. You may only require to pass field values to be inserted and the *suffix* to the `D.final_diagnosis_` field.

An example code snippet is shown below:

```
drop procedure if exists proc_insert_icd9;
delimiter //
create procedure proc_insert_icd9( final_diagnosis_suffix int )
    begin
        declare suffixId int;
        declare sql_insert_str varchar( 255 );
        declare sql_select_str varchar( 255 );
        declare sql_temp varchar( 255 );
        set suffixId = final_diagnosis_suffix;

        set sql_insert_str = 'insert into DimTableA(visit_no, patient, facility, icd9, icd9_flag, ip_op) ';
        set sql_select_str = concat( 'select D.registration, D3.med_number, D3.Hosp_Id, D.final_diagnosis_', suffixId, ', ''d'', IF(D3.Admit_Type in(1,2,3), ''Inpatient'', ''Outpatient'' ) from svch_dischs3_s D3, svch_diags_s D' );

        select concat( sql_insert_str, sql_select_str ) into @sql_temp;

        prepare stmt from @sql_temp;
        execute stmt;
    end;
//
delimiter ;
```

Now try calling the procedure that many number of times you require with correct suffix value for `final_diagnosis` field as parameter.
**Example**:

```
call proc_insert_icd9( 18 );
call proc_insert_icd9( 19 );
```

**Note**: You can modify procedure to include

1. more input parameters to handle a where clause, etc..
2. a where clause to the select statement.