# SQL Query to List Unused Numerical IDs

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table indexed on column=ID and it is a 5-digit integer.

It is a very old table and was never auto incremented.

I want to list all unused IDs.

I can do it with a `SELECT * ORDER BY` statement and then run the result against an incremented `for()` loop, but I was wondering if anyone knows if a SQL Query Statement to do this within MySQL or if you have a more clever method than the approach I am planning to take.

Thanks

Comment: What is your DBMS? You shouldn't ever `SELECT *`. Always specify a column list.

Comment: Do you have any other table with autoincremented id field from 1 up to 10000?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the reason for your question @AndrewLogvinov -- but the answer is no

Comment: The nature is that if you have such a table you can use `select id from table1 where id not in (select id from table2)`.

Comment: Don't miss the point of my question @njk -- I really never do a SELECT * -- I am merely here to see if someone has a clever solution. I can solve this easily in the fashion I mention, but I am always looking to learn new and more creative methods for doing things.,that's all.

Comment: Ah interesting approach @AndrewLogvinov -- I'll think about that solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the approach I would take.

1. Create a `number` table going from 1 to n (n being your largest ID). Numbers can be generated using a query such [as this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2652051/679449).
2. Perform a `LEFT JOIN` to the `number` table and fetch only `NULL` results.

### [See this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d22e/1)

Comment: Alternatively to creating a numbers table, you can create a [generator view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751318/creating-a-numbers-table-in-mysql).

Comment: Yes, @njk that is the same thing that AndrewLogvinov suggested above. Looks like you both have the best solution.

Comment: @H.Ferrence I've added a demo for you. Also, Andrew is suggesting to use an existing table that may have a continuous auto-incremented id.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a query like this

```
    SELECT id+1 as startId, (SELECT MIN(t3.id) -1 FROM table t3 
       WHERE t3.id > t1.id) as endId
    FROM Table AS t1
    WHERE 
    NOT Exists 
        (
           SELECT t2.id
           FROM Table as t2
           WHERE t2.id+1 = t2.id
        )
    HAVING (SELECT MIN(t3.id) -1 FROM table t3 
       WHERE t3.id > t1.id) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

i know this works with inserts ... maybe also works with updates.... would test it but im on a windows pc right now and no mysql installed :)

```
select @i := 1;
update tbl set id = @id:=@id+1;
```

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/autoincrement-value-mysql/

UPDATE:

its tested now and works very good... start with

```
select @i := 0;
```

so that your first entry in the db starts with 1;

Comment: what i understood is that you want to cleanup your table... means reindex all your entries starting with the first until the last one... the above will do exactly that ... but i think you will have to tell your mysql the highest id of your table... otherwise it will start autoincrementing the last id you had before