# HOWTO Make a Function With Loop/Repeat In MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, loops

I'm trying to get rid of a boring task of clicking on the create button of my GUI for creating new rows so I've decided to define a function to do that as many times as i want it to...
here's the code, but it returns an error in NAVICAT:

```
CREATE FUNCTION AddRow (number INT)
    BEGIN
        SET @x = 0;
    REPEAT
        INSERT INTO 'result' () VALUES ()
        SET @x += 1;
    UNTIL x > @number END REPEAT;

    END
call AddRow (10)
```

Error:

```
[SQL]CREATE FUNCTION AddRow (number INT)
    BEGIN
        SET @x = 0;
    REPEAT
        INSERT INTO 'result' () VALUES ()
        SET @x += 1;
    UNTIL x > @number END REPEAT;

    END
call AddRow (10)

[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
        SET @x = 0;
    REPEAT
        INSERT INTO 'result' () VALUES ()
        SET @x += ' at line 2
```

Comment: You should try to avoid procedural (loop/goto) code in a relational database.

Comment: Also, what you want is a "numbers table". There are many examples on the web - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751318/creating-a-numbers-table-in-mysql

Comment: @StingyJack: Well i'm not trying to write anything for production use.
only as a query to be executed when i need it, it only applies new rows to db when i call the function.
what u mentioned in the second comment is rather complex for a simple task.  but if u have any other solution i would be happy to hear it.

Comment: I dont think MySQL allows for anything simpler. Other RDBMS have simpler techniques, and you can always search for "numbers table MYSQL" to try and find better examples.

Comment: Why dont you just add a text box to the gui for "#of rows", and have the gui just call the add row that many times?