# Count all occurances of different characters in a column

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have two columns:

```
Table: MyTable

myString 
----------
 abaa
 abb
 a
 bc
```

I'm looking for a query that would return the count of each char within the myString column. In this case, it would return :

```
letter     count
-----------------
a            5
b            3
c            1
```

The only way I found to count chars was by a convoluted deletion method (count the length without the char, delete the char, and then recount), so I'm wondering if there would be a way to accomplish this more complicated task.

Comment: Do you have to do this in MySQL?  I think it'd be easier in <whatever language you are using>.

Comment: Good point! Can't believe I didn't think about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be slow (as will likely any solution in SQL), but you can use a [`numbers` table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751318/creating-a-numbers-table-in-mysql) to split apart the letters and count them:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(myString, number, 1) AS Letter,
  COUNT(*) AS LetterCount
FROM
  numbers n
  JOIN myTable mt
    ON n.number <= CHAR_LENGTH(mt.myString)
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(myString, number, 1)
```

<kbd>[Working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0eda3/2)</kbd>

Comment: Cool way to get around this. Thanks for sharing the tidbit about the numbers table!

Comment: Don't use `LENGTH` use `CHAR_LENGTH`.

Answer (score 2):

You are quite close to the goal. You can achieve this with the following query :

```
select sum(length(mystring)) - sum(length(replace(mystring, 'a', ''))) as count_a
from mytable
```

Comment: This will only work for the letter `'a'`... what about all other characters?

Comment: @Michael Build a query for each character you want to count ... Or build a query with a column for each character. You cannot do better.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer It looks like Michael Fredrickson has a good SQL only solution.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is using **stored procedures**. 
See the <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2912/1)</kbd>.

I really think this isn't the best solution, i don't recommend use this in production with a table that contains a significative length of data.

But, for study or experimental purposes. 
Hugs.