# Selecting values with more than one occurrence of a character in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Let me explain my question with an example

Consider the following column of values

```
City
-------
Chennai
Delhi
Mumbai
```

Output I want is

```
City
-------
Chennai
Mumbai
```

When you look at the values 'Chennai' has two 'N's and 'Mumbai' has two 'M's

What is the query to find the values that satisfy the above said condition

I am using MySQL

Comment: What do u mean by filtering. What output do u want?

Comment: I mean to SELECT these type of values

Comment: @Dineshbabu Can you let us know the exact condition means any string repeating a char twice of more it should come, what if two characters satisfies the condition like `hyderabad` a twice.. d twice..

Comment: Actually just the character **a** sorry for confusing you guys

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use some of the logic from here and then filter that way [Count all occurances of different characters in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551764/count-all-occurances-of-different-characters-in-a-column)

Answer (score 0):

Can u try this. If you want you can create function and accepts dynamic value and pass to the corresponding function

```
IF(LEN('Chennai')-LEN(REPLACE('Chennai', 'N', ''))>1 )
 Select 'Chennai'
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution if city names contain only latin characters

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
 FROM table1 c CROSS JOIN
(
   SELECT 0 n UNION ALL
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 5 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) b
    ORDER BY n
) n
  WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(city) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(LOWER(city), CHAR(97 + n.n), '')) > 1
```

Output:

```
|    CITY |
|---------|
|  Mumbai |
| Chennai |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/866732/3)** demo

Comment: @dineshbabu Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use stored procedure for this. Please check my code -

Create table statement -

```
CREATE TABLE `Cities` (
  `City` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Added cities to table and created procedure -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_SplitString`()
BEGIN
   DECLARE front TEXT DEFAULT NULL;
   DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE arrayText longtext default "";
   DECLARE Value longtext DEFAULT "";
   DECLARE val longtext DEFAULT "";
   DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
   DECLARE cityCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM `Cities`;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

   OPEN cityCursor;
   loop_through_rows:
   LOOP  
   FETCH cityCursor INTO Value;

   IF done THEN
      LEAVE loop_through_rows;
   END IF;

   SET val = Value;
   iterator:
   LOOP 
     IF LENGTH(TRIM(val)) = 0 OR val IS NULL THEN
       LEAVE iterator;
     END IF;
     SET front = LOWER(SUBSTRING(val,1,1));


     SET count = LENGTH(Value) - LENGTH(REPLACE(LOWER(Value), front, ''));


     IF count > 1 THEN
       IF LENGTH(TRIM(arrayText)) = 0 THEN
         SET arrayText = Value;
       ELSE
         SET arrayText = CONCAT(arrayText,",",Value);
       END IF;
       LEAVE iterator;
     END IF;
     IF LENGTH(TRIM(val)) > 1 THEN
       SET val = SUBSTRING(val,2,LENGTH(TRIM(val)));
     ELSE
       SET val = "";
     END IF;

   END LOOP;
   END LOOP;

SELECT * FROM `Cities` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(City, arrayText);

END
```