# How to select static values column?

Tags: mysql, select

When we run query `SELECT 1` then MySQL returns one row with one column containing 1.
How should I build the query to get one column with several rows containing specified values? I think it can be something like `SELECT VALUES(1,2,3) AS v`?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Do you have a few, or lots and lots? A `UNION` chain is needed.

Comment: If you need a large range, I would recommend creating a temporary table and inserting into it with a loop. Otherwise, just use UNIONs

Comment: I want to JOIN a table with this set of IDs. I know about WHERE..IN, but I want to JOIN exactly, because it will make a selection more quickly than WHERE..IN. It should look like JOIN with temporary table, but with this value set instead of table.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Union is usually the quick way to create a defined set of values in a single data set

```
SELECT 1 as Value
UNION
SELECT 2 as Value
UNION
SELECT 3 as Value
```

If this is going to have lots of values, then building a tally/number table might be a more preferable method. [Creating a "Numbers Table" in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751318/creating-a-numbers-table-in-mysql)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    VALUES (1,2), (3,4)
)
t1 (c1, c2)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: "VALUES is a DML statement introduced in MySQL 8.0.19" - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html

Comment: I followed the document and add ROW() wrap to each new row like `VALUES ROW(1,2),ROW(3,4)`, then it works fine!

Comment: A little side note: the syntax in mysql is different: 

VALUES ROW(1,2), ROW(3,4);

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the keywork `UNION`

```
SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 ...
```