# Duplicate line according to Quantity amount

Tags: mysql, duplicates

Good Day

I Have a Table Called POs and it looks like this:

```
ID | ITEM | Description | Quantity | Amount |
----------------------------------------------
1  | A123 | Item 1      |    2     |  500   |
2  | A676 | Item 2      |    3     |  300   |
```

Is there a way to duplicate the line (as View) according to the `Quantity amount and Number` it ie.

```
ID  | ITEM | Description | Quantity | Amount | Number |
-------------------------------------------------------    
1   | A123 | Item1       |    2     |  500   |   1    |
1   | A123 | Item1       |    2     |  500   |   2    |
2   | A676 | Item2       |    3     |  300   |   1    |
2   | A676 | Item2       |    3     |  300   |   2    |
2   | A676 | Item2       |    3     |  300   |   3    |
```

Thanks

Comment: Why you need this anyway. I'm asking because maybe you may need some other thing that could be done with some aggregate function.

Comment: And your example I don't think that could be implemented as there has to be an unique key

Comment: I use this for the sales guys, I have created a booking system where they can book stock out. On our Purchase Order it comes as a one liner but for this to work I need to brake it up as shown. I have done this from excel and the data does push to MySQL I was just hoping that I can get past the excel step. We don't have to wory about the Unique for now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
select
t.*,
numbers.n
from
t
inner join 
(
 select aa.a + 10 * bb.b + 100 * cc.c + 1000 * dd.d as n from
 (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) aa,
 (select 0 as b union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) bb,
 (select 0 as c union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) cc,
 (select 0 as d union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) dd
) numbers
on t.Quantity >= numbers.n
where numbers.n != 0
order by t.id, numbers.n
```

It seems just a bit complicated because I create a table with numbers from 0 to 99 on the fly. It's a good idea to have a table for as much numbers as you need and join to this one.

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3adb4/14)</kbd>

Comment: Oh yeah. If OP will have `quantity=1000` he will be surprised. It's a common problem about sequence generation and it has (in general) two different solution in MySQL, but not as you've described.

Comment: Why will he be surprised? What are you talking about? Works perfectly with 11, too: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa56a/1

Comment: Typo, that was 1000 (you're multiplying `10*x+y`, where `max(x)=9`, `max(y)=9` - so max will be 90+9, but I've just typed 1000)

Comment: Still don't understand...Yes, when he needs more than 99 he will have to create more numbers on the fly or like I said generate a table with numbers anyway which makes life easier. So? What's the point. And my sequence generation works fine. Or can you just describe in detail what's wrong with it?

Comment: And of course there are other ways like shift operations and so on which are shorter but harder to understand for beginners. I picked this one....

Comment: The wrong is to assume that quantity will be restricted with some maximum. You can't "re-write" SQL, it's application's structure thing. I think it's a task to application, not to MySQL (but - yes, that's because MySQL has no sequences supported)

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. But my solution, which is btw more like a proof of concept, still is applicable when the OP might know that he will never have a higher quantity than a certain amount.

Comment: If it's so important to generate any meaningful number in MySQL, there's [common solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751318/creating-a-numbers-table-in-mysql) to that.

Comment: Looks Great and does what i need it to do, only problem is when I want to save the query as a view I get this error: **View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause**

Comment: Then create a table like in the link that Alma Do posted in the comment above yours and join to it instead of having the subquery.

Comment: Hi FancyPants, Sorry I twook so long to get back about this. I had a look at your code again and I got it to work great in SQL Server. I have one question tough. I had a look at your code and cannot see what I need to change for it to go past 99. I want to change it to MAX 2500

Comment: @RuanduPreez I modified the query so the MAX is 9999