# Insert lots of rows with only a number

Tags: php, mysql, performance, optimization

What is the fastest way to create 899 rows in a table, using only the number. The column isn't autoincrement.

Currently I create a query like this:

```
$a1=range(100,999);
$a1=implode('),(',$a1);
$a1='INSERT INTO groups (val) VALUES('.$a1.')';
```

it gives a huge query like this:

```
INSERT INTO groups (val) VALUES(100),(101),(102),(103),(104),(105),(106),(107),(108),
(109),(110),(111),(112),(113),(114),(115),(116),(117),(118),(119),(120),(121),(122),
(123),(124),(125), etc etc etc....
```

I wonder if there is a faster and nicer way to do this?

Comment: I'd recommend to use stored procedures for this kind of task.

Comment: See the *Number Table* generator @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751318/creating-a-numbers-table-in-mysql

Comment: I don't think this question deserved a down-vote. The OP showed what was attempted so far (which works), and asked a targeted question. I know the code snippet is incomplete (and doesn't mention the programming language), but the question is clear.

Comment: Faster and nicer... Isn't this fast enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have a faster way of doing that. Look at **[MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html)**

> The time required for inserting a row is determined by the following
>   factors, where the numbers indicate approximate proportions:
>
> Connecting: (3)
>
> Sending query to server: (2)
>
> Parsing query: (2)
>
> Inserting row: (1 × size of row)
>
> Inserting indexes: (1 × number of indexes)
>
> Closing: (1)
>
> This does not take into consideration the initial overhead to open
>   tables, which is done once for each concurrently running query.
>
> The size of the table slows down the insertion of indexes by log N,
>   assuming B-tree indexes.
>
> You can use the following methods to speed up inserts:
>
> **If you are inserting many rows from the same client at the same time,
>   use INSERT statements with multiple VALUES lists to insert several
>   rows at a time. This is considerably faster** (many times faster in some
>   cases) than using separate single-row INSERT statements. If you are
>   adding data to a nonempty table, you can tune the
>   bulk_insert_buffer_size variable to make data insertion even faster.
>   See Section 5.1.4, “Server System Variables”.

With one query you save the `Connecting`, `Sending query to server` , `Closing`, plus MySQL optimizing your query.

Also, if you're only inserting around 1000 rows with so little data, the insertion is very fast so i wouldn't be worried about performance in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I'll stick with this big query then :-)

Answer (score 0):

For a range of numbers a smaller query can be used if you want:-

```
INSERT INTO groups (val)
SELECT Hundreds.a * 100 + Tens.a * 10 + Units.a AS aNumber
FROM
(SELECT 0 AS a UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Hundreds,
(SELECT 0 AS a UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Tens,
(SELECT 0 AS a UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Units
HAVING aNumber BETWEEN 100 AND 999
```

Not sure this saves you anything much though.