# Create View that separates a line in various

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

I have this table:

```
-- Product --
id_product
date-begin
date_end
period
```

And fill with:

```
id_project | date_begin | date_end | period
1 | 2015-01-01 | 2016-01-01 | 1 month
2 | 2015-12-01 | 2015-12-29 | 1 week
```

I wanted the View to show it:

```
id_project | date_payment
1 | 2015-02-01
1 | 2015-03-01
1 | 2015-04-01
...
1 | 2016-01-01
2 | 2015-12-01
2 | 2015-12-08
2 | 2015-12-15
2 | 2015-12-22
2 | 2015-12-29
```

How do I divide a line into several?

Comment: I am using mysql, and I want create a View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pretty basic example of what you can do to solve your problem.

The first thing it does is create some numbers views for you so we can join later. these are some cartesian joins to create large sets of number.. 16 to 1 million..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_16
AS SELECT 0 n UNION ALL SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2  UNION ALL 
   SELECT 3   UNION ALL SELECT 4  UNION ALL SELECT 5  UNION ALL
   SELECT 6   UNION ALL SELECT 7  UNION ALL SELECT 8  UNION ALL
   SELECT 9   UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL
   SELECT 12  UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL 
   SELECT 15;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_256
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n << 4 ) | lo.n ) AS n
     FROM generator_16 lo, generator_16 hi;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_4k
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n << 8 ) | lo.n ) AS n
     FROM generator_256 lo, generator_16 hi;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_64k
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n << 8 ) | lo.n ) AS n
     FROM generator_256 lo, generator_256 hi;
```

Found that code here.. [Creating a "Numbers Table" in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751318/creating-a-numbers-table-in-mysql)

Then you can create your view using this statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW product_payment_dates
AS SELECT   p.id_project,  
        CASE  
            WHEN p.period LIKE '%month%' THEN DATE_ADD(p.date_begin,INTERVAL n.n MONTH)
            WHEN p.period LIKE '%week%' THEN DATE_ADD(p.date_begin,INTERVAL n.n WEEK)
            WHEN p.period LIKE '%day%' THEN DATE_ADD(p.date_begin,INTERVAL n.n DAY)
        END as date_payment
FROM    Product p
JOIN    generator_64k n ON (CASE 
                        WHEN p.period LIKE '%month%' THEN DATE_ADD(p.date_begin, INTERVAL n.n MONTH)
                        WHEN p.period LIKE '%week%' THEN DATE_ADD(p.date_begin, INTERVAL n.n WEEK)
                        WHEN p.period LIKE '%day%' THEN DATE_ADD(p.date_begin, INTERVAL n.n DAY)
                    END) <= p.date_end
ORDER BY p.id_project, date_payment;
```

This looks at the period to determine if you should add months, weeks, or days to the begin_date to build the list.  You can also customize this to pull the interval number from the period, in case you want to add 2 months, or 3 weeks etc..

Here is a [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4661/1) of everything

Answer (score 0):

All you need is **dates** table then do a `Inner Join` your table with the `dates` table

```
select * 
from yourtable A
inner join Dates_table b 
on b.dates between a.date_begin and a.date_end
```

If you are using `Sql Server` check this [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) for **dates** table code

Comment: I want to create a view as I showed above. Starting a record, I intend that this View be generated ((date_end - date_begin) / period) rows.

Comment: @Giest So you'd just slap this answer inside a 'create view' statement, but you need a table that has the list of dates to join to.

Comment: Then this way is impossible. Thanks
Not having this issue solution, it must eliminate it?